# Unable to boot Centos 6.3 from live CD

Tags: windows-7, boot, operating-systems, centos-6

This seems a strange question to ask. The the same cd boots perfectly on one PC but gives the message-

```
 slab error in kmem_cache_destroy():cache 'Acpi-Operate':can't free all objects
 slab error in kmem_cache_destroy():cache 'Acpi-parse':can't free all objects.
 -
 -
 -
Kernel Panic Not Syncing Attempted to kill init!
-Pid 1 ,comm: init Not tainted 2.6.32-279.e16.i686 #1
 [<c083bfbc>]? panic+0x68/0c11c
 [<c045a501>]? do_exit+0x741/0x750
 [<c045054c>]? do_group_exit+0x3c/0xa0
 [<c045a5c1>]? sys_exit_group+0x11/0x28
 [<c0409a9f>]? sys_enter_do_call+ox12/0x28
panic occured,switching back to text console.
```

on the other.
What could have gone wrong?

Comment: Huh? How exactly are you "booting on windows"?

Comment: Post those other "unintelligible lines". Kernel Panic is a boilerplate statement of a fatal error. The specific cause is probably nearby in the output.

Comment: When you say it works on Windows XP but not Windows 7, do you mean that you're trying on two separate PCs which happen to have different OS's installed? Or, are you trying to use the live CD within VMs hosted by those two OS's?

Comment: @terdon I have Windows 7 installed on my laptop.And i was trying to install Centos from the live cd that i had downloaded.

Comment: @Windos Yes they are two seperate PCs,with different OSs and no VMs included.

Comment: @ZacB that sounds scary<br/> at the top of screen were <br/> slab errror in kmem_cache_destroy():cache 'Acpi-Operate':cant free all objects.<br/> slab error in kmem_cache_destroy():cache 'Acpi Parse':Cant free all objects.

Comment: Other lines were-<br/> Pid 1,comm:init Not tainted 2.6.32-279.e16.i686#1 <br/> Call trace <br/>[<co83bfbc>]?panic+o\0x68/0x11c    [<c045a501>]? do_exit+ox741/0x750 </br> [<c045054c>]?do_group_exit+ox3c/0xa0<br/> [<c045a5c1>]?sys_exit_group+0x11/0x28 <br/> [<co409a9f>]?sys_enter_do_call+0x12/0x28. panic occured,switching back to text console. phew!

Comment: Please edit your question to include the extra information instead of adding it as a comment. It is much easier to read that way.

Comment: I edited the question to show what is actually being asked. The installed operating system is irrelevant, your problem is that you cannot install Linux on a specific computer.

Comment: Thank you, yes that is precisely what the question is.It should rather be 'it worked on my desktop but not on the laptop'.

Comment: Try a different CentOS version; you may be making the liveCD with a kernel module that doesn't play nicely with the laptop's hardware. Also run Memtest or similar on the laptop; this problem could conceivably be caused by problems in RAM.

Comment: @ZacB I ran the memtest and there seems to be no problem with the RAM.The version I used was centos 6.3.It booted fine within VMware but again, it doesn't let me install it as a virtual machine.

Comment: Can I install centos on an exernal hard disk and go ahead?